# How to terminate all thread groups when any one of thread group having an exception

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

We used multiple thread groups in projects for parallel execution like below
ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

Here my question is how to terminate other thread groups when exception comes in any one of the thread group.

thanks.

Comment: Try to see if you can use the afterExecute method that exists on ThreadPoolExecutor(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). If you extend it for example. protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { }

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a separate service which

- tracks the relevant threadpools
- tracks an exception flag
- you delegate task submission to so it can wrap Runnables in a try-catch which sets the exception flag to true
- periodically checks if the exception flag is true and, if so, attempts to shutdown all relevant threadpools

For example you could have something like below.

```java
public class ThreadpoolService {
    private final AtomicBoolean threadpoolException = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Set<ExecutorService> threadPools = new HashSet<>();
    private final ScheduledExecutorService tracker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public ThreadpoolService() {
        // Start a thread tracking if an exception occurs in the threadpools, and if so attempts to shut them down
        tracker.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if (threadpoolException.get()) {
                shutdownThreadPools();
            }
            // Run the tracker every second, with an initial delay of 1 second before the first run
        }, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private void shutdownThreadPools() {
        // For each threadpool create a completable future which attempts to shut it down
        final var threadpoolStopTasks = threadPools.stream()
            .map(tp -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    tp.shutdown();
                    // Await termination, force if taking too long
                    if (!tp.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        tp.shutdownNow();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    tp.shutdownNow();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Create a completable future from all of the above stop tasks, wait for it to complete then
        // stop the executor this tracker is running in
        CompletableFuture.allOf(threadpoolStopTasks.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
            .thenApply((v) -> {
                tracker.shutdownNow();
                return null;
            })
            .join();
    }

    public void submit(ExecutorService threadPool, Runnable task) {
        threadPools.add(threadPool);
        threadPool.submit(() -> {
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do stuff
                threadpoolException.set(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
        shutdownThreadPools();
        tracker.shutdown();
        if (!tracker.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            tracker.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your program

```java
    final var threadpoolService = new ThreadpoolService();


    // Then wherever you use a threadpool delegate to the above for task submissing
    final var tp1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    threadpoolService.submit(tp1, () -> {
        // some task which may fail exceptionally
        return;
    });
```

When your program needs to shutdown for some other reason

```java
    threadpoolService.shutdown();
}
```

Of note is that an exception triggerring the shutdown of these threadpools is not recoverable i.e. the threadpools and ThreadpoolService are no longer in a functional state after shutdown and really, this should trigger the end of the program - you could enhance this to register a shutdown hook which ends the program.

It should also be noted that I've made a lot of assumptions inc.

- use of the default fork-join pool for CompletableFutures (you can just pass your own executor service)
- expectation the CompletableFuture.allOf will finish in a timely manner (you can add a timeout)
- hardcoded time intervals (you can make these configurable)

It also doesn't cover the below, both of which can be resolved by using a guard (maybe `threadpoolException`) on appropriate methods and returning some value or throwing an exception as appropriate

- race conditions on the various methods (e.g. calling shutdown while a shutdown is in progress)
- calling submit following a shutdown